# Uniqueness of analytic center manifold

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, hyperbolic-dynamics

In a book, i have read a remark which says that the center manifold of an equilibrium point of a differential equation is not unique in general but is unique in the class of analytic manifold. The author does not give any proof, it is just a remark.

Does anyone have a reference for the proof of this fact?

Thank you !

Comment: The Taylor expansion of the center manifold is unique to any order. That makes the center manifold unique in the class of analytic manifolds, if an analytic center manifold exists.